# 404 on Every Template and TPL group

Tags: ee2, htaccess, 404

Trying to setup a sub-directory with a separate EE installation. All is well with the installation, I got a few templates and tpl groups setup.

Whenever I try and view the template (Template manager -> TPL Group -> view) I always get a 404.

For a better understanding here is my site: http://warpedcoders.com/ here is the subdomain: http://warpedcoders.com/charlie/ and here is the 404 http://warpedcoders.com/charlie/news/page_content

My .htaccess currently looks like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /charlie/
        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Could anybody help me out?

Comment: where is the htaccess in the subdir or in the maindir? Also, your rewrite rule looks odd, could you try ```RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]``` or with a questionmark before the $1. (and set site root in config and index.php)

Comment: see http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html

Comment: Sorry, the htaccess is in the subdir and unfortunately that didn't work). Another thing to note is that I have removed index.php from the url in the admin panel

Comment: please take a look at the docs (linked above) no rewritebase and especially look at the exceptions part (subdirs etc.)

Comment: Well that is where I started, it didn't work so I tried editing it but to no avail. I might move it to a subdomain and see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your 404'd page works with index.php: http://warpedcoders.com/charlie/index.php/news/page_content

So, try this for your .htaccess rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  ## Removes index.php
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
  # IF YOU HAVE WEBSITE IN A SUB FOLDER: comment out above line, uncomment below line, & replace 'SUBFOLDERNAME'
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /charlie/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And make sure your **/expressionengine/config/config.php** file has this for your Index File setting:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Comment: [I created a similar thread here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/26873/htaccess-rules-for-subdomains) but I thought I would see if you can assist me as well. The way the client has the server set up is causing my nav to break. I followed your instructions above and it isn't working for me. I went wrong somewhere. Can you assist? Thanks :/